# How to disable sourcemaps in @sentry/nextjs package

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, sentry

I have a nextjs project and I am using [@sentry/nextjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/nextjs) package for error logging.
I want to disable sourcemaps in my deployed application's client side.

I have read through [this](https://blog.sentry.io/2018/07/17/source-code-fetching) blog by sentry but still not able to disable sourcemaps

Answer (score 0):

> I have a nextjs project and I am using @sentry/nextjs package for error logging. I want to disable sourcemaps in my deployed application's client side.

It appears you want to disable generation, this has nothing to do with Sentry  - The Sentry setting simply stops it from fetching sourcemaps  when one is supplied in the generated JS file.

Check your `next.config.js` - If you have an entry like this, then remove, do a prod build and deploy again

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/source-maps